# can't get log on socket?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using slf4j and logback API for logging. I configured log on socket. But when I am trying to read text I found "??" rather then logs. Please help me if anyone of you have an idea about it.

Comment: It will help if you show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THelper is right - more information would help us debug your setup.

Blindly, I recommend reading through this and checking out the examples in the SLF4j distribution for comparison: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender